Issue with gallery image loading randomly
I have a problem loading a fetched gallery: when I load the gallery page, images load as expected, but when I go to a different page, for example home page followed by coming back to gallery page, the images are not loaded and the container is totally empty, in other words, jumping from page to page makes the images in gallery page load randomly. If I was not clear please let me know so I can elaborate more n_n'. Thanks in advance.

This is how I get my fetched gallery
  import { reactive} from 'vue';
  
  export default {
    transition:'fade',
    layout: 'layout_port',
    data(){
      return{
        
        filter:'original',
        indexGal: null,
        sortmenu:['original','fanart','concepts','graphic design'], 
        gallery: reactive (['static images here']),
        
      }
    },
    computed:{
      fetchedGallery() {
        if (this.filter) {
          return this.gallery.filter(i => i.cat === this.filter)
        }
        return this.gallery
      }
    },
  
  }
  

And this is how I show the images
#portfolio
    v-main
      v-container(fluid).ma-0.pa-0
        v-layout(justify-center)
          v-flex(xs12 text-xs-center)
            v-card(flat color='transparent')
              ul
                li(v-for='(category,index) in sortmenu' :key='index' :item='category' @click='filter = category' :class="{ active: category == filter }")  {{ category }}
                

              v-layout()
                v-flex(xs12 sm6 offset-sm3)
                  v-card(flat color='white').gallery
                    v-container(grid-list-sm fluid)
                      v-layout(row wrap)
                        //keep-alive
                        v-flex(v-for='(image,index) in fetchedGallery', :key='index' :item='image',xs6 sm4 d-flex)
                            v-card.d-flex(flat tile color='transparent').galim.pa-4
                              v-img.grey.lighten-2(:src='image.url', :lazy-src='image.url', aspect-ratio='1' @click='indexGal = index')
                    br
                    no-ssr
                      LightGallery(:images='fetchedGallery' :index='indexGal' :disable-scroll='true' @close='indexGal = null' interfaceColor='rgba(255,253,238)' background='rgba(0,0,0,0.95)')
                      


You mention (A) "the images are not loaded and the container is totally empty" but then also mention (B) "makes the images in gallery page load randomly". This sounds like 2 different issues. So which problem do you have exactly?

Hello, thanks for the response, the problem is as the title itself, images are loading totally random, I know the images are not visible in the example code, I'm just not allowed to show these urls, that's all, sorry for the missunderstanding.

Any errors in the console/network devtools? Also, I am not sure if Pug is the most reliable/easy way to handle troubleshooting of a Vue template haha.

This issue is most likely caused by the way vue handles reactivity and component lifecycle. What I would suggest is using <keep-alive> around <router-view> tag to avoid unnecessary destruction and recreation of components during navigation.
<keep-alive>
    <router-view />
  </keep-alive>

This will ensure that the component that is once loaded, won't get destroyed when you navigate to another page.
Also, I would also suggest using reactive to declare your gallery images.
gallery = reactive([
'insert images here.'])

To debug the issue, please console log gallery after you navigate back to check if it's acting as expected.
Another solution can be to call fetchGallery inside a onMounted hook (so you are sure it's fetching once the component is being mounted), but this is mostly suggested when you fetch from an API.

Hello, thanks for the response and the detailed information, unfortunately I'm still facing the issue with the images after following your instructions.

Could you please send a more complete overview of your code or edit your question? Also, are you fetching data from API or it's a static data? Did you also try the onMounted() lifecycle hook? Please try to console.log after each step to see how the fetchGallery method reacts.

Hello, thanks once again for the response, please find below the requested information:
Images are static (urls taken fron a cdn)
console.log does not show any issues or maybe I'm doing something wrong.
I have updated my question to show more detailed code.
thanks once again for the help.
Best regards.
